# How to compare two array with condition in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like below :

Array_1 : ($array1 - after print the array)

```
Array ( [companyid] => 589 [company_name] => log_tracking_24 [username] => admin@log24.com [emp_count] => 0 [user_id] => 764 [module_expenses_benefit] => 1 [module_time_attendance] => 1 [module_bank_ftp] => 0 )
```

Array_2 : ($array2 - after print the array )

```
Array ( [company_name] => log_tracking_241 [username] => admin@log241.com [password] => [cpassword] => [emp_count] => [module_expenses_benefit] => on [user_id] => 764 [companyid] => 589 )
```

I compare the two arrays and get different values . for this i  try the following,

```
array_diff($array1,$array2);
```

Finally i get the following result :

```
Array ( [company_name] => log_tracking_24 [username] => admin@log24.com [emp_count] => 0 [module_expenses_benefit] => 1 [module_time_attendance] => 1 [module_bank_ftp] => 0 )
```

but what i want is ,

In my first array : `$array1['emp_count']` having the value 0  and  my second array : `$array2['emp_count']` having the value Null ( '' ).

In this type of situation i want to remove the key and vlaue while the time of array_diff.

How to do this. i try the unset() function . but no use.

Comment: use `array_filter()`

Comment: This is what @Saty want to say: `array_diff(array_filter($array1), array_filter($array2));`

Comment: But @Saty, I have a doubt, Is the array filter clear the array value `$array1['emp_count'] = 0`??

Comment: then what is the correct way

Comment: try with array_filter than see whats happen...

Comment: @FrayneKonok check below answer for your queries!!

Comment: But @ Frayne if i try means the key 'module_bank_ftp' also removed. what can i do if my second array $array2['module_bank_ftp'] = on

Comment: It also removed from the final array..

Comment: but i dont want to remove the key['module_bank_ftp'] if it is having value on in second array.

Comment: You must go with saty, He make different custom functions to remove different things.

Comment: okay thanks for your info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** to remove empty elements:

```
$emptyRemoved = array_filter($linksArray);
```

To remove value 0 and empty.  you may use the following:

```
$emptyRemoved = remove_empty($linksArray);

function remove_empty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, '_remove_zero');
}

function _remove_zero($value) {
  return !empty($value) && $value === 0;
}
```

Pass your both array to `remove_empty()` function then use `array_diff()`

```
$arr1 = remove_empty($array1);
$arr2 = remove_empty($array2);
array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: Error in exception handler: Method [fatal] does not exist. in /home/ashokpc/MyProjects/Laraval/betaiworkforcehrm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php:283

Comment: $postData1 = remove_empty($postData);
             function remove_empty($postData) {
  return array_filter($postData, '_remove_zero');
}                                                                                            

function _remove_zero($value) {
  return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
}                                                                                                                   $difference_val = array_diff($old_values,$postData1);
             print_r($difference_val);

Comment: One mistake by me use && instead || at `_remove_zero` check example https://3v4l.org/dmSOW

Comment: but if i use that means i have an error like above i was sent

Comment: that's was your full error message. have you call any method name fatal??

Answer (score 1):

Yes `array_filter` did the work for you. Just use:

```
array_diff(array_filter($array1), array_filter($array2));
```

See the example:

```
$entry = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => '',
             5 => 0
          );

print_r(array_filter($entry)); //Array ( [0] => foo [2] => -1 )
```

So array_filter removes the `false`, `null`, `''`and `0`.